# How can I separate and center the buttons?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to leave the buttons one underneath the other and center them, but I do not know how to do that. Currently they are side-by-side and are not centralized.

Buttons:

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png"/>
<button ion-button round class="button">Acessar</button>
<button ion-button round class="button">Tutorial</button>
<button ion-button round class="button">Sobre</button>
```

Css:

```
.wallpaper {
    background-color: #25d298;
}

.button {
    background-color: #d24125;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Center them relative to what? In general to center a button you apply either `text-align: center` to the parent, or `display: block; margin: auto` to the button. Also `margin: 20` is invalid - you need to give a unit like `20px` or `20%` or whatever.

Comment: Relative to width.

Comment: Just 'text-align' isn't working.

Comment: is one of these what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KqJdGa

Comment: Yes. I tried exactly that way and it did not work.

Comment: When I let margi: 20px, they come back do the left side.

Comment: How can I let a distance between them?

Comment: add a margin-bottom. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/NgoNjO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should put your buttons inside of DIV elements and then you should be able to text-align them inside of the DIV.

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png"/>
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button ion-button round class="button">Acessar</button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button ion-button round class="button">Tutorial</button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button ion-button round class="button">Sobre</button>
</div>
```

Then for the CSS:

```
.button-wrapper {
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    background-color: #d24125;
}
```

Notice the space is now controlled by the wrapper? That's the best approach opposed to styling the buttons.

If you wanted to have the buttons inside of your wrapper DIV without a DIV per button, you can just do something like this:

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png"/>
<button ion-button round class="button">Acessar</button>
<button ion-button round class="button">Tutorial</button>
<button ion-button round class="button">Sobre</button>
```

**With accompanying CSS:**

```
.button {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Comment: I got it, but cannot I use just one div? for all the items

Comment: Added in an example of no wrapper DIV for buttons. The key is to set each button as block, then margin auto for its left and right values, with 20px of margin on the top and bottom. The auto for margin is what does the centring.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the HTML:

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button ion-button round class="button">Acessar</button>
  <button ion-button round class="button">Tutorial</button>
  <button ion-button round class="button">Sobre</button>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 20%;
}

.button {
  margin: 10px auto 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

- display: block causes the buttons to be treated as block-level elements, forcing each one to a new line.
- auto for the left/right margin centers each button within whatever container holds them. the div is included only as an example.
- 10px top and bottom margin gives you the spacing above/below.

[codepen.io/johndoyle/pen/xrMwvy](https://codepen.io/johndoyle/pen/xrMwvy)

Hope this helps - good luck!